# Error with APIDemos sample android

Tags: android

```
W/ResourceType( 5404): Bad XML block: header size 160 or total size 8126656 is larger than data size 0
W/ResourceType( 5404): Bad XML block: header size 160 or total size 8126656 is larger than data size 0
W/ResourceType( 5404): Bad XML block: header size 160 or total size 8126656 is larger than data size 0
W/ResourceType( 5404): Bad XML block: header size 160 or total size 8126656 is larger than data size 0
W/ResourceType( 5404): Bad XML block: header size 160 or total size 8126656 is larger than data size 0 
C:\ApiDemos\res\menu\content_actions.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\menu\content_actions.xml:38: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\menu\content_actions.xml:43: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\menu\content_actions.xml:47: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\menu\list_select_menu.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueType' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:18: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:25: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:25: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueType' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\animator_set.xml:25: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\color_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueFrom' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\color_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\color_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\object_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\object_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueType' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\anim\object_animator.xml:17: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueFrom' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueType' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueFrom' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueTo' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'valueType' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'propertyName' in package 'android'
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'interpolator' with value '@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint').
C:\ApiDemos\res\animator\fragment_slide_left_enter.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:19: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:19: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:26: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:31: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:31: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:35: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
C:\ApiDemos\res\layout\surface_view_overlay.xml:35: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent')
```

I am using Apidemos from api-17

I have modified android manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

How to resolve these errors ?

Comment: tried rebuilding and cleaning the project?

Comment: Uncheck 'Build Automatically' , Clean and build again.